# Extjs 4.2.2 Ext.Window.Show is not showing the data loaded in Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs4.2

I want to display the data loaded in the store object in Windows. I can see the store is loaded with the correct data. But when it is passed to the Panel and Panel is passed to the Window, when Window.Show is called, only the column names are displayed, but not the data which is stored in the Store object.

Please help me with this. The code snippet is as follows:`enter code here`

```
var store1 = new Ext.data.Store({
                autoLoad:true,
            fields: [{
                name: 'Index'
            }, {
                name: 'VrfNames'
            }]
        });
        var vrfData = [
            ["HI", "Hello"]
        ];
        store1.loadData(vrfData);
        console.log("Loaded " + store1.getCount() + " records");
        //Could verify data is loaded properly


        // creation of panel
        var vrfNamesPanel = new Ext.grid.Panel({
            store: store1,
            columns: cm,
            height: 250,
            width: 700,
            enableHdMenu: false,
            buttons: this.buildVrfNamesPanelButtons(),
            buttonAlign: 'center',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            //floating: true,
            //closable : true//,
            listeners: {
                scope: this
            }

        });


        // creation of new window
        this.vrfNamesWindow = new Ext.Window({
            layout: 'fit',
            closeAction: 'hide',
            plain: true,
            title: "VRF Names ",
            items: vrfNamesPanel,
            enableTabScroll: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            width: 700
        });

        this.vrfNamesWindow.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/135d) for you.

I dont know what is your `cm` columns settings so I added it, I believe that issue was there.

Comment: I tried the working fiddle, It works with Extjs 6 , but the problem is still present, when I tried to run it with Ext JS 4.2.1.883 Neptune(The data in the store object is not shown in the window). Could you please help me with any workaround for this? As we are bound to extjs 4.2.

Comment: Fiddle updated, remove `autoLoad: true` as you load data locally (atleast in the fiddle).

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me! :)